# Which GAN is the best for data augmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-models, gan

I have around 200000 images and I want to augment the data by generating more of them. Images do not have classes, because they are the same object and are used for the task of object detection.
Can I use a generic GAN like https://github.com/ypxie/HDGan ?

Comment: what kind of image data you have, medical or other?
what do you want to do after augmentation? object detection or classification? Maybe you need give us more information and your goal, ultimate goal.